# Seleção de tags dupla no visual code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Está acontecendo um problema no meu VS code, as tags estão simultaneamente selecionadas em cima e em baixo, tem alguma configuração para deixar somente a de cima[image: ![seleção dupla]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be3hD.png) 
 Desde já agradeço!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse é um "problema" que vei com a última atualização **1.41** e eles chamam isso de `mirror tag cursor` como vc pode ver aqui https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_html-mirror-cursor

Para desabilitar isso vc precisa mudar `html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag` que está ativo por padrão agora.

Vai em `Settings`, e pesquisa por `html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag`, depois é só desmarcar o `checkbox`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Hugocsl!! Deu certo aqui!! eu já tenho uma extensão Auto Rename tag que faz isso, mais de uma maneira mais discreta!  Você também achou estranho essa atualização?

Comment: @PinheiroNeto cara eu tb já usava uma extensão que pareava as duas tag, mas agora parece que o VS Code incorporou essa função tb... como tenho usado pouco nem reparei se melhorou ou piorou. Cara se vc acha que a resposta resolveu seu problema lembre-se de marca-la como aceita nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta. Assim sua pergunta não fica pendente de resposta aceita, mesmo já tendo sido resolvida. Abs

Comment: Marquei, Valeu mais uma vez!!

Comment: @PinheiroNeto valeu meu caro 